# Casting with bool for checkbox gives error "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

1. I have this checkbox that is getting data from a bit column called Complimentary. Here it is needing a cast:

[image]

2. Here I add the cast of bool to fix the problem.

[image]

3. However it produces an error. Why? I've been trying to figure it out and cannot see why, as I have other checkboxes that use this same code and work properly.

[image]

It says:

```
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Comment: Try casting to `bool?` as it could be a null value you are dealing with.

Comment: maybe its string? then you need to use convert class. Convert.ToBoolean

Comment: What is the value of `reader["Complimentary"].GetType().Name`?

Comment: @NikolaiDante I think this might be the case, but Visual Studio doesn't recognize `bool?`

Comment: @YacoubMassad Okay, I just tried this it and says the value is null, which then changes to "DBNull". I would think that null should mean that the checkbox would default to false / not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
object value = reader["Complimentary"];

if(value != null && value != DBNull.Value)
{
    CbIsComplimentary.Checked = (bool)value;
}
else
{
    //Optionally handle null value, e.g.:
    //CbIsComplimentary.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use unboxing to unbox the type of string to a type bool I doubt one is a subclass for another or vise versa. You have to use predefined function for that.

```
Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Complimentary"].ToString());
```

[Convert.ToBoolean Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx)