# Checking a value from DB to see if it's a boolean and setting combobox as such throws exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a small project I've been working on. What I'm doing is - I add a value in the database, the table looks as such...

```
ProductID, ProductName, Status
1          Gold         0
```

Status is a Bit(1)

Since I only have two values in the drop down for Status, I use the combobox.selectedIndex - to capture the value of the field - either 0 or 1.

Once I insert the values into the table, I try to populate a datagrid with everything saved in this particular table in DB...

Here's what I'm doing...

```
MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from PRODUCTS ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["ProductCode"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["ProductName"].ToString();
            if ((bool)item["Status"]) // Trying to capture the value from DB and set the combobox with the correct .Value
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = "Active";
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = "Deactive";
            }
```

The exception I get comes from this line of code..

```
if ((bool)item["ProductStatus"])
```

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

It looks like this is a popular error and trying to google gives me a hundred different scenarios. ANyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you look at item["ProductStatus"].GetType() you will see what the actual type is.  I would suspect that it will be a string or int type.  To convert to a bool, you could use bool.Parse(item["ProductStatus"]) or even better bool.TryParse...  This might be a problem with the MySql provider?

Comment: @KiwiPiet - i suspect MySql might be the issue here. Don't have SQL SERVER to test it with but most likely woulnd't have that issue

Comment: try `Convert.ToBoolean(item["ProductStatus"])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting with bool for checkbox gives error "Specified cast is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887386/casting-with-bool-for-checkbox-gives-error-specified-cast-is-not-valid)

Comment: @hagello it deals with a checkbox and SQL SERVER - mine is MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a `bit` column as you say in your post then there shouldn't be any issue at all but mostly it's not. Moreover,  you are going round instead going straight ... I mean change your query like below and directly bind to your grid

```
SELECT productId, productName,
case when Status = 1 then 'Active' else 'Deactive' end as Status
FROM PRODUCTS
```

Bind it to the gridview

```
ySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("query here ", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; //bind the data
```

Comment: That seems to do the job. Thanks.